# leaflet draw: custom tooltip for polyline that shows angle and distance from last point

Tags: geometry, range, leaflet, tooltip, draw

I have created a simple Leaflet map and added Draw based on documentation [here](http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/docs/leaflet-draw-latest.html#leaflet-1-0-examples) (using 1.0). I downloaded and am using all of the different js files in the example. I would like to change the tooltip for polylines to show the distance from last vertex instead of the total line length and (if possible) an angle from the last vertex. I am going to be mapping building with walls that are usually at right angles. Unfortunately, my js skills are mediocre at best and I do not know where to start. Any suggestions? Thank you.